# Installing libpng on Mac OS X Yosemite using brew fails

Tags: macos, homebrew, libpng

I have a problem with installing libpng on Mac OS X Yosemite using brew.

The output looks like this:

```
    brew install libpng
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/libpng-1.6.16.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: f7b47fcf9d4111075745b04b6fbdb63062982bca
Actual: a2fd3379ea944f6b2f97fb0f79b7b85cb3e14d0b
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libpng-1.6.16.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.16/libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100,0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 31855a8438ae795d249574b0da15b34eb0922e13
Actual: a2fd3379ea944f6b2f97fb0f79b7b85cb3e14d0b
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I think this output is very strange because the SHA1 Hash is the same for two different files.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. I think there is something messed up with this release.

Comment: Got the same thing, think there is an issue with downloads.sf.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourforge is currently in disaster mode... The files brew downloads are probably containing something like:

```
<html><head>
<title>Testing</title>
<!-- <script src="/js/jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//sourceforge.net/js/mirrors.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sf.js"></script>
<script>
var DR_loc = DR_parse_hash_url();
if (DR_loc) {
    DR_sf_main(DR_loc);
} else {
    window.location.href = 'http://sourceforge.net/home.html';
}
</script>
</head><body>
<noscript>
We're sorry -- the Sourceforge site is currently in Disaster Recovery mode, and currently requires
the use of javascript to function.  Please check back later.
</noscript>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Still in disaster recovery mode. As a matter of fact, downloading travels from sf via curl does not work at all. It is more than one week though, which seems rather a long period for a disaster recovery.